# Remote FTP Backup -Tar archive+ encrypt+ split to a remote ftp

Tags: curl, ftp, backup, tar, remote-backup

I have a huge directory(200+ gb) for backup. I want upload the tar file simultaneous to a remote ftp. (pipeline, stdout, stdin etc.)

I don't want write a data to local hdd. I have a ssd hdd

this code doesn't work.( yes i know the problem is split command!)

```
tar cvzf - /backup | openssl aes-256-cbc -salt -k "password" | split -b 1000m | curl -u user:password ftp.site.com/backup.tar -T -
```

this code working but writing split files to hdd.

```
tar cvzf - /backup | openssl aes-256-cbc -salt -k "password" | split -b 1000m - bkup
for file in bkup*
do
curl -u user:password ftp.site.com/$file -T $file
done
```